# How Do I Move Char Alphabetically from Z to A in C?

Tags: c, cs50

Current situation:

User runs my program and gives it a key. Let's say that key == 1. User is prompted for text. If they enter the word `"Hello"` the key rotates each char by 1 and the output is `"Ifmmp"`.

THE PROBLEM:

If the user inputs the word "zoo", the output (if the key == 1) is {pp. The output should be "app". How do I get the output to go from Z back to A for any char entered that crosses the letter Z.

Here's the code I constructed (with much help) to build this functionality:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{           
    int counter = 0;    
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <strlen(argv[1]); k++)
        {
            if (isdigit(argv[1][k]))
            {
                counter++;         
            }
        }

        if (strlen(argv[1]) == counter)                
        {
            string s = get_string("plaintext: "); 
            printf("ciphertext: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(s); j++)              
            {
                int c = (int) s[j];  
                printf("%c", c + atoi(argv[1]));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }              
        else
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        }
    }
    else   
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }                          
}
```

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: How do you get to 4 o'clock after adding 3 hours to 11 o'clock? You use the modulo operator

Comment: 3 hours after 11 o'clock is 2 o'clock...

Comment: No need to call `atoi (argv [1])` for every input string char. You can call it only once and assign it to a tmp variable.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour when the input character is not alphabetical?

Comment: If a user enters invalid data, they get a message saying `Usage: ./caesar key` rather than a description of what is wrong with their input.  That is sloppy.  Give a precise error message detailing what is wrong. If a particular character is invalid, say that. If no key is given, specify that.  Writing good error messages is difficult, but extremely important.  Practice it in simple cases like this.

Comment: What is `string s`?  Is this C++, or is string a typedef for `char *`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell : Given `int main(int argc, string argv[])` is appears `string` is indeed  an alias for `char*` (and a bad idea).

Comment: and don't call `strlen` inside the for loop. Store the length in a variable instead[

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `string` is typedef'ed to be `char*` in `cs50.h` (for details see the description to the `cs50` tag)

Comment: @alk Harvard is generally considered a reputable school.  It is extremely disappointing that they would typedef `string` in this way.  There is sometimes a fine line between an appropriate level of abstraction and mere obfuscation, but this is an instance where the gulf is broad!

Comment: @Cubo78 Good question. When the char inputted is not alphabetical it needs to remain the same in output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Although that makes sense, that is what the assignment calls for us to do. This is C and I used string s to store the input from user. To be clear, this is only one of several assignments. I think they're trying to teach us certain concepts by focusing strongly on the concept even if other areas are taught later in the course.

Answer (score 1):

When I have a problem like this where I want a number to loop back to the start once it crosses a threshold (like a clock), I find modulus to be the best solution.

Example:

```
int hour = 11;
hour = (hour + SOME_VALUE) % 12; // This will ensure hour is always a value between 0 and 11
```

Now, you'd have to check whether the letter is a capital letter (check an ASCII table), and apply a different modulus.

Comment: I'm trying to use modulo but not sure what the syntax would be. So far I've written (atoi(argv[1]%26). I've read about using the entire alphabet or printing the integer value as opposed to the char...trying to resolve both

Comment: Lower case letters start at 97 (on an ascii table), and go to 122. So the math would be: ((current_character - 97 + offset) % 26) + 97. Remember, this is only for lower case letters. Upper case, replace 97 by 65.

Comment: I tried the curr char equation but it still exceeds z and goes to 123. Should the last + 97 be - 97 instead?

Answer (score 1):

Since C does not guarantee the adjacency of the letters, you should create a table that maps the input letter to the appropriate output letter.

A compact way to do this is just with a special string.

```
const char *map =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA";
```

With this string, you can implement a simple function that searches for the input character, and return the output character.

```
int rot1(int c) {
    const char *x = strchr(map, c);
    return x ? x[1] : c;
}
```

The `strchr` call searches `map` for the first occurrence of `c`. If it's found, it returns the pointer where in the `map` it is. The value in the location after this pointer is the output value.

The trick used here is that the string in `map` has an extra `a` after `z`. Similarly for `Z`. Since `strchr` finds the first occurrence, the extra occurrence doesn't affect the correctness of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I will just explain you the principle and it is your task to code the source code:

Iterate through your given string in order to get each char. Get the value of the proper char and increment it. For example, 'h' has value value 104. 104 incremented equals 105 which corresponds to the char 'i' which is exactly what you want. Ultimately, what you need to do is to add the condition if the char value is 122 which is 'z'. In this case do not increment but set it manually to 97('a').

That is it. You simply need to do the same task for the capital letters too. Set 90('Z') manually to 65('A').

Keep in mind that you should check whether the user input is even in the range of the latin alphabet as the principle would not work with crazy unicode chars.